# Communication between C++ Client and C# Server trough Network Stream

Tags: c#, c++, shell, networking

I have a little shell programm where the client is written in c++ and the server in c#. The client should just write the server some awnseres of cmd commands. Everything is working perfect except for one thing: the server outputs total rubish!!

this is the server in c#:

```
    static NetworkStream Stream;
    static byte[] AWNSER = new byte[255];

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpListener listen = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 123);
        listen.Start();
        Stream = listen.AcceptTcpClient().GetStream();

        Stream.BeginRead(AWNSER, 0, 255, HNDLR, null);
        while (true)
        {
            var str = Console.ReadLine();
            byte[] MESSAGE = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str + "&& cd");
            Stream.Write(MESSAGE, 0, MESSAGE.Length);
        }
    }
    static void HNDLR(IAsyncResult a)
    {
        Stream.EndRead(a);
        Stream.BeginRead(AWNSER, 0, 255, HNDLR, null);

        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(AWNSER));
    }
```

this is the clients code in c++

```
FILE *fp;
char AWNSER[255];
WSAData wsaData;
WORD DllVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);

if (WSAStartup(DllVersion, &wsaData) != 0) //no error
{
    cout << "Winsock startup failed";
}
SOCKADDR_IN addr;
int addrlen = sizeof(addr);
addr.sin_port = htons(123);
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("199.166.177.22");
SOCKET Connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
if (connect(Connection, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, addrlen) != 0)
{   /*ERROR*/
}
else
{
        fp = _popen("dir", "r");
        while (fgets(AWNSER, 255, fp) != NULL) {
            cout << AWNSER;
            send(Connection, AWNSER, 255, NULL);
            AWNSER[255];
        }
        _pclose(fp);
}
```

here is an example of what the output of the server is:

```
 Volumeseriennummer: BAF0-6BB2
Windows


    ?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

 olumeseriennummer: ABF1-7AA3
 Windows
 ??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

 olumeseriennummer: ABF1-7AA3
 Windows
 ??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\User\Source\MyProblem
 ?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

 erzeichnis von C:\Users\User\Source\MyProblem
 ?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
30.07.2018  19:08    <DIR>          .
 myProblem
```

Tank you very much for your help

Comment: ah ok so the server is reading things that he already raed and so it gets a little messy. can you show a example of how you would solve the problem in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client is sending the entire `AWNSER` array even if it is not completely filled in.  You should send only what is actually entered.

The server is outputting whatever it receives, but without any regard to how many bytes it actually receives.  You need to take the received byte count into account.

TCP is a streaming transport. There is no 1-to-1 relationship between sends and reads. So you need to buffer incoming data, and structure your data in such a way that the client can signal when it is done sending a message, and the server can know where one complete message ends and the next begins. A null terminator or line break will suffice in your simple example.

Don't display partial strings. Wait for a complete string to arrive before then displaying it. Otherwise you risk corrupting the data when decoding something that is not ready to be decoded yet.

In your server handler, don't call `Stream.BeginRead()` before calling `Console.WriteLine()`. Call it after you are done using `AWNSER`. Otherwise you risk `AWNSER` being overwritten before you have a chance to use it.

Try something more like this:

Server:

```cs
static NetworkStream Stream;
static MemoryStream Data;
static byte[] AWNSER = new byte[256];

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TcpListener listen = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 123);
    listen.Start();
    Stream = listen.AcceptTcpClient().GetStream();
    Data = new MemoryStream();
    Stream.BeginRead(AWNSER, 0, AWNSER.Length, HNDLR, null);
    while (true)
    {
        var str = Console.ReadLine();
        byte[] MESSAGE = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str + "&& cd\n");
        Stream.Write(MESSAGE, 0, MESSAGE.Length);
    }
}

static void HNDLR(IAsyncResult a)
{
    int numRead = Stream.EndRead(a);
    if (numRead == 0) return;

    Data.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
    Data.Write(AWNSER, 0, numRead);

    byte[] bytes = Data.GetBuffer();
    int idx = 0;
    int size = (int) Data.Length;

    while (idx < size)
    {
        int found = Array.FindIndex(bytes, idx, size - idx, b => b == 0x0A);
        if (found == -1) break;
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(AWNSER, idx, found-idx);
        idx = found + 1;
    }

    if (idx > 0)
    {
        Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, idx, bytes, 0, size - idx);
        Data.SetLength(size - idx);
    }

    Stream.BeginRead(AWNSER, 0, AWNSER.Length, HNDLR, null);
}
```

Client:

```cpp
bool sendRaw(SOCKET skt, void *buf, int bufsize)
{ 
    char *p = (char*) buf;
    while (buflen > 0)
    {
        int sent = send(skt, p, buflen, 0);
        if (sent == SOCKET_ERROR) return false;
        p += sent;
        buflen -= sent;
    }
    return true;
}

...

FILE *fp;
char AWNSER[256];
WSAData wsaData;
WORD DllVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);

if (WSAStartup(DllVersion, &wsaData) != 0) //no error
{
    cout << "Winsock startup failed";
}

SOCKADDR_IN addr;
int addrlen = sizeof(addr);
addr.sin_port = htons(123);
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("199.166.177.22");

SOCKET Connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (Connection == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    /*ERROR*/
} 
else
{
    if (connect(Connection, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, addrlen) != 0)
    {
        /*ERROR*/
    }
    else
    {
        fp = _popen("dir", "r");
        while (fgets(AWNSER, 256, fp))
        {
            int len = strlen(AWNSER);
            while ((len > 0) && ((AWNSER[len-1] == '\r') || (AWNSER[len-1] == '\n'))) --len;
            AWNSER[len++] = '\n';
            cout.write(AWNSER, len);
            if (!sendRaw(Connection, AWNSER, len)) break;
        }
        _pclose(fp);
        //... 
    }
    closesocket(Connection);
}
```